# What is the C++ equivalent of binary.write in Golang?

Tags: c++, go, endianness, ruby-c-extension

I am working on project in C++ that adopts many ideas from a golang project.
 I don't properly understand how this binary.write works from the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write) and how I can replicate it in C++. I am stuck at this line in my project.

```
binary.Write(e.offsets, nativeEndian, e.offset)
```

The type of e.offsets is `*bytes.Buffer` and e.offset is `uint64`

Comment: Is `e.offsets` a file or buffer?

Comment: @kennytm, I'm not go expert but it looks like from the docs it is: `binary.Write(destination, endian, data_to_write)`

Comment: @ArafatK, is the endian aspect something you care about?

Comment: @kennytm I have edited the question.

Comment: @EvanTeran I have read the documentation, I am looking for C++ equivalent.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question. Do **you** care about ensuring a specific endian?

Comment: @EvanTeran OP's code clearly said "nativeEndian".

Comment: I doubt there is a direct equivalent, since IIRC `binary.Write` uses reflection which isn't available in C++.

Comment: @kennytm, right, but that may be incidental, or may be a requirement for correctness. I am trying to find out which it is.

Comment: @ArafatK OK. What is the type of the corresponding `e.offset` in C++? `std::stringstream` or `std::vector<uint8_t>` or something else?

Comment: @kennytm Basically STRINGs are encoded as an array of 8-byte offsets so offset is number I am not sure of the exact type.(Sorry!!)

Comment: @ArafatK I don't get it. Perhaps you should post what you have currently translated on the C++ side.

Comment: @kennytm The code is golang is open source. This is the link 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/go/tensor.go#L381

Comment: @kennytm This is the link to my code.
https://github.com/Arafatk/tensorflow.rb/blob/master/ext/sciruby/tensorflow_c/files/tf_tensor_helper.cc#L261

Comment: @ArafatK Yes but we want to know what you have done in the C++ part. BTW why are you translating TensorFlow to C++? [It already has a C++ interface](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/).

Comment: @kennytm Its for tensorflow ruby. I didn't want to create a whole story so I just asked about this subpart.

Comment: @kennytm Also that function crashes and because I have probably done something wrong and I am sure it has something to do with the question I have asked.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ standard libs, it is generally up to you to deal with endian concerns. So let's skip that for the time being. If you just want to write binary data to a stream such as a file, you can do something like this:

```
uint64_t value = 0xfeedfacedeadbeef;
std::ofstream file("output.bin", ios::binary);
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
```

The cast is necessary because the file stream deals with `char*`, but you can write whatever byte streams to it you like.

You can write entire structures this way as well so long as they are "Plain Old Data" (POD). For example:

```
struct T {
    uint32_t a;
    uint16_t b;
};

T value2 = { 123, 45 };
std::ofstream file("output.bin", ios::binary);
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value2), sizeof(value2));
```

Reading these things back is similar using `file.read`, but as mentioned, if you REALLY do care about endian, then you need to take care of that yourself.

If you are dealing with non-POD types (such as `std::string`), then you will need to deal with a more involved data serialization system. There are numerous options to deal with this if needed.

Comment: Please check OP's comments on the question. Welp, I don't know, the question's scope seems very non-C++.

Comment: @kennytm, I agree, the quesiton is very vague. It **seems** (not being a Go expert) that `binary.Write` does something like writing the fields of a "structure" to a stream as a basic binary serialization format. 

I do think that my answer (given the lack of better context) is as close as we can get for now.